# Woocommerce Analytics Error: 414 (Request-URI Too Long )

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Recently, my Woocommerce analytics dashboard stopped loading the analytics and report and now gives me an Error 414 (Request URI to Long )

The Error in more detail:

GET https://webiste/wp-json/wc-analytics/reports/revenue/stats?order=asc&interval=day&per_page=100&after=2020-11-01T00%3A00%3A00&before=2020-11-03T23%3A59%3A59&fields%5B0%5D=gross_sales&fields%5B1%5D=refunds&fields%5B2%5D=coupons&fields%5B3%5D=net_revenue&fields%5B4%5D=taxes&fields%5B5%5D=shipping&fields%5B6%5D=total_sales&_locale=user 414 (Request-URI Too Long)

and is in : api-fetch.min.js?ver=8773a93ea0d1278a2eaa147fdb6eb96d:2

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to a webserver configuration or change, rather than a change in Woocommerce itself.

This 414 error is the webserver (or a web proxy or other intermediary) saying 'You sent me a request for a page, and the url/uri you gave me is too many characters long'. That server will have some kind of upper limit on how long those requests can be. That request is 331 characters long.

The Woocommerce apis are particularly sensitive to this because they pass all the filtering arguments as GET uri parameters (as apposed to POST vars).

You can probably fix this by increasing the limit. In Nginx it's a setting called large_client_header_buffers. In Apache it's LimitRequestLine. Your own server/service may be different.